# Inserting Missing value NOT working GoLang

Tags: go, slice

I'm trying to Insert a Int value to slice if it is missing in that.

My Code :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func AppendIfMissing(slice []int, i int) []int {
    for _, ele := range slice {
        if ele == i {
            fmt.Println(i)
            return slice
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("i value is ", i)
    slice = append(slice, i)
    return slice
}

func main() {
    slice1 := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
    AppendIfMissing(slice1, 60)
    fmt.Println("slice after adding :", slice1)
}
```

OutPut :

```
    i value is  60
    slice after adding : [1 2 3 4]
```

Appending to slice is not happening.What is wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`AppendIfMissing` returns a slice which you need to affect to a variable.
`append(slice, i)` creates a new slice, which means the parameter slice isn't modified, it refers to a all new slice:

- which is returned at the end
- which needs to be affected to a variable

  ```
  slice1 = AppendIfMissing(slice1, 60)
  ```

See [go playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/0ZhlAOGdZt).

---

I agree that the article "[Arrays, slices (and strings): The mechanics of '`append`'](http://blog.golang.org/slices)" mentions

> Even though the slice header is passed by value, the header includes a pointer to elements of an array, so both the original slice header and the copy of the header passed to the function describe the same array.
>   Therefore, when the function returns, the modified elements can be seen through the original slice variable.

But the function in that article wasn't using `append`:

```
func AddOneToEachElement(slice []byte) {
    for i := range slice {
        slice[i]++
    }
}
```

> the *contents* of a slice argument can be modified by a function, but its *header* cannot

And by doing

```
slice = append(slice, i)
```

you modify the header,  you reallocate the resulting slice to a completely different array.
That won't be visible outside of the function.

Comment: Thanks for new insight!!

Answer (score 0):

More generic version of AppendIfMissing, it requires go version >= 1.18

```
func AppendIfMissing[T comparable](slice []T, i T) []T {
    for _, ele := range slice {
        if ele == i {
            return slice
        }
    }
    return append(slice, i)
}
```

Comment: Does not answer the real question.